# mount remote windows share from centos

Tags: linux, vpn, cifs

I am trying to setup a script that will:

1. Connect to a windows share
2. Using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, upload the two files into their appropriate db tables
3. Umount share

Situation:
I can currently vpnc into this remote machine

Problem:
I cannot

```
mount -t cifs //ip.address/share /mnt/point -o username=u,password=p,port=445
mount error(110)  Connection timed out
```

I am attempting to do this manually first
Remote server is open to port 445

Questions:

1. Do I even need to vpnc in first?
2. Do I need to do route add for the remote ip/mask/gw after vpnc?

Thank you!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The **mount.cifs** file is provided by the **samba-client** package. This can be installed from the standard CentOS yum repository by running the following command:

```
yum install samba samba-client cifs-utils
```

Once installed, you can mount a Windows SMB share on your CentOS server by running the following command:

**Syntax:**

```
mount.cifs //SERVER_ADDRESS/SHARE_NAME MOUNT_POINT -o user=USERNAME
```

**SERVER_ADDRESS:** Windows system’s IP address or hostname

**SHARE_NAME:** The name of the shared folder configured on the Windows system

**USERNAME:** Windows user that has access to this share

**MOUNT_POINT:** The local mount point on your CentOS server

I am mounting to a share from **\\10.11.10.26\snaps**

Make a directory under mount for your reference

```
mkdir /mnt/mymount
```

Now I am mounting the snaps folder from indiafps02, User name is the Domain credentials, i.e. Mydomain in this case

```
mount.cifs //10.11.10.26/snaps /mnt/mymount -o user=Girish.KG
```

Now you could see the content by typing

```
ls /mnt/mymount
```

So, after performing your task, just fire umount command

```
umount /mnt/mymount
```

That's it. You are done.

Comment: What about `cifs-utils`? I had to install this as well.

Comment: After much deliberation and squabbling about I just installed PHP on the windows server and curled the files up to my server - works a charm - I did this over a year ago.

Comment: After installing the samba-client, mount.cifs is not recognized

Comment: I have done small modification to achieve the required result i.e mount.cifs //{IP/hostname}/{sharedfolder} {/home/virtual_machine_folder} -o username=username,password=""
,vers=2.0

Comment: Hello:  @girish-kg
Any idea how this is not working for my case? 
I've been facing mount error(112): Host is down ISSUE

mount.cifs //IP/cloudfolder /lib_core -o user=root

Answer (score 1):

no need to install "samba" and "samba-client", only "cifs-utils" using command

yum install cifs-utils

after that in windows share the folder you would like to mount in centos if you didn't do that already ("c:\interpub\wwwroot" in my case).

make sure you share it with a specific username whom your know the password for ("netops" in my case).

create a directory in centos in which you would like to mount the windows share in to ("/mnt/cm" in my case).

after that run that simple command as a root

mount.cifs //10.16.0.160/wwwroot /mnt/cm/ -o user=netops

centos will prompt you for the windows username password.

you are done.